# How to find unique rows based on max date value

Tags: r, date

I have the following dataset:

df

```
email_id           date
xyz@gmail.com   23-12-2018 21:33
xyz@gmail.com   23-12-2018 21:34
xyz@gmail.com   23-12-2018 21:35
xyz@gmail.com   23-12-2018 21:36
xyz@gmail.com   23-12-2018 21:37
abc@yahoo.com   23-12-2018 21:09
abc@yahoo.com   23-12-2018 21:10
abc@yahoo.com   23-12-2018 21:11
abc@yahoo.com   23-12-2018 21:12
abc@yahoo.com   23-12-2018 21:13
lmn@outlook.com 23-12-2018 21:44
lmn@outlook.com 23-12-2018 21:45
lmn@outlook.com 23-12-2018 21:46
lmn@outlook.com 23-12-2018 21:47
```

I am trying to find unique emails having the latest time stamp. The output is something as shown below:

```
email_id    date
xyz@gmail.com   23-12-2018 21:37
abc@yahoo.com   23-12-2018 21:13
lmn@outlook.com 23-12-2018 21:47
```

Can this be done using dplyr or should i trying some sql group by query? Help needed.

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(email_id) %>% mutate(date=max(date))`

Comment: `df %>% group_by(email_id) %>% slice(which.max(date))` that is

Comment: Try `sqldf("select email_id,max(date) from df group by email_id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
DT[, date := as.POSIXct(date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz = "")]
DT[, .SD[which.max(date)], email_id]
          email_id                date
1:   xyz@gmail.com 2018-12-23 21:37:00
2:   abc@yahoo.com 2018-12-23 21:13:00
3: lmn@outlook.com 2018-12-23 21:47:00
```

Where:

```
DT <- fread("email_id,           date
xyz@gmail.com,   23-12-2018 21:33
xyz@gmail.com,   23-12-2018 21:34
xyz@gmail.com,   23-12-2018 21:35
xyz@gmail.com,   23-12-2018 21:36
xyz@gmail.com,   23-12-2018 21:37
abc@yahoo.com,   23-12-2018 21:09
abc@yahoo.com,   23-12-2018 21:10
abc@yahoo.com,   23-12-2018 21:11
abc@yahoo.com,   23-12-2018 21:12
abc@yahoo.com,   23-12-2018 21:13
lmn@outlook.com, 23-12-2018 21:44
lmn@outlook.com, 23-12-2018 21:45
lmn@outlook.com, 23-12-2018 21:46
lmn@outlook.com, 23-12-2018 21:47")
```